# Does the PHP mail function return true if email is incorrect

Tags: php

I am making a system that will be used to collect data from users. I know some will be spam! I just want to know if the mail function returns false if the email is not correct?

Say I have.

```
   <?php

    $to = "fake@fake.com";
    $header = "From: {$to}";
    $subject = "Hi!";
    $body = "Hi,\n\nHow are you?";

    if (mail($to, $subject, $body, $header)) {
          echo("<p>Message successfully sent!</p>");
    } else {
          echo("<p>Message delivery failed...</p>");
    }

   ?>
```

Which message will be printed if the email is not correct?

If it does return false I want a "flag" to be stored with it in that database so the admins can review it and delete it.

Comment: Have you tried running that code to see what's returned?

Comment: Please define `not correct`. It can be either `not valid` (= not complying to RFC 2822), in which case `mail` will return `FALSE`, or `not existing`, in which case `mail` will happily return `TRUE`.

Comment: Just a fake email that someone has likely made up. it is not real but will still fit the format of an email address e.g fake@gmail.com

Comment: There are some questions on SO that talk about checking if an email address exists, here's [one of them](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4664254/how-to-check-whether-an-email-id-exists-or-not)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Not necessarily.

Per the [manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php), the [`mail()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php) function will return `true` if the message is accepted for delivery - but doesn't guarantee that it will be delivered:

> Returns TRUE if the mail was successfully accepted for delivery, FALSE
>   otherwise.
>
> It is important to note that just because the mail was accepted for
>   delivery, it does NOT mean the mail will actually reach the intended
>   destination.

Comment: So is there a way to find out if a email is "real" or is validating it against something like a regular expression the best I can do?

Comment: @Will Your best bet would be to scan the server's mail logs for each email that was sent; a normal result will have something similar to "status=sent" for valid emails or "status=bounced" for invalid ones - all depends on the program your server uses and it's logging format. Also, you'll need to scan it *later* than right when the email is sent - it can take several minutes to send, pending traffic.

Comment: That sounds like a lot more work than I was planning on doing for this haha. Thanks for the answers.

Comment: @Will It can be a lot of work - pending on what level of information you want =P.

Answer (score 3):

All the server can tell you is the mail was accepted to be passed on or not. Unless you wrote an invalid email address or such to the point it was "no email" and so the server would reject it, then no, sadly, all it can say is "yes the mail was put in the electronic post" or "No it wasnt" it cant tell you if it gets there, read, or otherwise.

Answer (score 1):

In the case you have outlined in your comment

```
fake@gmail.com
```

as far as the mail system is concerned this is a valid email address.

> Message successfully sent!

will be displayed. The mail function makes no guarantee about getting to the recipient. And before you ask its not possible to check.

Comment: Thanks :/ was hoping that this wasn't the case.

Comment: email protocols were written in the 1970's before anyone had to worry about spam ! :)