# php mailer - no failure delivery notice

Tags: php, phpmailer

Hello I am sending emails using php mailer class. This is the script:

```
    include 'phpmailer/class.phpmailer.php';
    $mail = new PHPMailer();

    $mail->IsSMTP();
    $mail->Host     = "smtp.xxxxx.org"; // SMTP server
    $mail->SMTPAuth = TRUE; 
    $mail->Username = 'myname@mynamedomain';   // SMTP username
    $mail->Password = 'password';               // SMTP password

    $mail->SetFrom('my_webmail.address@website.org');
    $mail->Sender = "my_webmail.address@website.org"; 
    $mail->ConfirmReadingTo = 'my_webmail.address@website.org';
    $mail->ReturnPath = "my_webmail.address@website.org";
    $mail->AddReplyTo("my_webmail.address@website.org");

    $mail->Subject = "phpmailer message"; 
    $mail->Body = "bla bla bla"; 

    $mail->AddAddress("whoto@otherdomain.com"); 


   if($mail->Send())  
   { 
   echo 'mail sent'; 
   }  
  else  
  { 
  echo 'Mailer Error: ' . $mail->ErrorInfo; 
  }
```

It works....but I'm not able to get a failure delivery notice when a user insert a non-existent webmail address.
Any suggest?   thanks

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked the similar questions before ask question ? If it is not please check it first.

[Check if email exist php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14448649/check-if-email-exist-php)

[How to check whether an email id exists or not?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4664254/how-to-check-whether-an-email-id-exists-or-not)

Comment: I checked but didn't find them...so I must check whether an email address exists or not via php script...is it impossible to get a failure delivery notice via phpmailer setting?  thanks

Comment: Till now I have never seen this facility from phpmailer, so for now my advice is follow those link and make your own validator for email.